# writing login information to the keychain failed

Tags: debian, github, chrome-os, visual-studio-code

I'm running Linux Debian v5.4.109-26094-g381754fbb430 on my Chromebook. Everything has been working until now.

On Sunday, I logged into VSC on another device using my account, then when I return to my personal PC, it starts acting up. I try signing into my GitHub account so I can have access to Git and stuff, but no avail.

The same error pops up every single time:

```
writing login information to the keychain failed with error 'The name org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files'
```

Can any of you please please please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using KDE (I had same problem with Manjaro KDE). I solved installing `gnome-keyring`

```
sudo apt install gnome-keyring
```

Comment: For an explanation: VS Code depends on `gnome-keyring` for credentials even if you are using other DEs. https://tips.initpals.com/kde-tips/fix-for-error-the-name-org-freedesktop-secrets-was-not-provided-by-any-service-files-in-kde/